# changing a global variable value in php

Tags: php, variables, global

Im Learining php and I'm Just confused with some teaches of w3schools!

```
<?php
$x = 5;
$y = 10;

function myTest() {
global $x, $y;
$y = $x + $y;
}

myTest();
echo $y; // outputs 15
?>
```

in this code it say's that the output will be 15 because we get the "y" variable value in myTest function! but how php does know that the "y" variable in `$y = $x + $y;` is the global one or new one ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global `$y` and the `$y` resulting from `$y = $x + $y` are the same variable. `global` doesn't define a different variable, it defines the 'scope' of the variable, ie, where it can be accessed within the script. So `$y = $x + $y` changes the value of the global variable.

If, for example, you rewrote the function like this:

```
function myTest() {
    $x, $y;
}
```

`$x` and `$y` would be different from the previously-defined variables because you did not define them as global.

Answer (score 1):

`$y` is global one inside `myTest()` function as you have declared:

```
global $x, $y;
```

so inside `myTest()` :

```
global $x, $y;//$x=5 and $y=10
$y = $x+$y; // value of $y will be over written by (10+5) and it will become 15
```

Just to clear your confusion more:

```
function myTest() {
   $y = 200; //local $y
   echo $y; //200
   global $x, $y;//now global $y will overwrite local $y
   $y = $x + $y;
   echo $y; //15
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So in this case we can't have local "y" variable in myTest function at all?!